# Unable to access the mapStateToProps form redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to react, I have setup some reduces of array of dishes, comments, promotions and leaders with redux. In my AboutComponent.js am trying to access `mapStateToProps` with the connect method that `react-redux` offers.

When I tried to get the required leaders reducer resource from the store It says that it is `undefined`. below is snippet of my About Component, I am accessing the same way following a tutorial and I am accessing the way the tutorial says to access the mapStateToProps as shown below. Can anyone help me understand why I am getting the undefined ?

**AboutComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import { FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native' ;
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
//import { LEADERS } from '../shared/leaders';
//1.import to connect to redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

//2.leaders state from store
const mapStateToProps = state => {
     return {
          leaders: state.leaders
     }
  
}



// Contact details array
const HistoryElement = [
    {
       part_one: 'Started in 2010, Ristorante con Fusion quickly established itself as a culinary icon par excellence in Hong Kong. With its unique brand of world fusion cuisine that can be found nowhere else, it enjoys patronage from the A-list clientele in Hong Kong.  Featuring four of the best three-star Michelin chefs in the world, you never know what will arrive on your plate the next time you visit us.',
       part_two: 'The restaurant traces its humble beginnings to The Frying Pan, a successful chain started by our CEO, Mr. Peter Pan, that featured for the first time the world\'s best cuisines in a pan.'
    } 
]

function History(props){
    //get the prop
    const history = props.history;
   
    if ( history != null) {      
        return(
           <Card title="Our History">
           {    
               history.map((u, i) => {       
                  return (               
                    <View key={i}>          
                       <Text>{u.part_one}</Text>                    
                       <Text></Text>
                       <Text>{u.part_two} </Text>                        
                    </View>    
                  );  
               })   
           } 
        </Card>                            
    )
  }
}

function RenderLeader(props) {
    //get the leaders array
    
   const leaders = props.leaders.leaders;

    const renderLeaderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
                <ListItem   
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    titleStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                    subtitle={item.description}
                    //3. Update the image from the server     
                    leftAvatar={{source: {uri: baseUrl + item.image} }}
                    />
        )
    }
    return (
        <Card title="Corporate Leadership">
            <FlatList 
                data={this.props.leaders.leaders} //HERE IS THE PROPLEM
                renderItem={renderLeaderItem}
                keyExtractor={Item => Item.id.toString() }
                />
        </Card>
        )
}

class About extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            history: HistoryElement
        }
    }
 
    //setup the navigation for the current class [Dishdetail]
    static navigationOptions = {
        title : 'About'
    }

    render(){
       return (
        <>
           <History history={this.state.history} />
           <RenderLeader leaders={this.props.leaders.leaders} />    // ALSO HERE IS THE PROPLEM
        </>
       )
    }
}

// the About comp to Redux store
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(About);
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { dishes } from './dishes';
import { comments } from './comments';
import { promotions } from './promotions';
import { leaders } from './leaders';

// Combines the reducers
export const ConfigureStore = () => {
      const store = createStore (
          combineReducers({
              dishes,
              comments,
              promotions,
              leaders
          }),
          applyMiddleware (thunk, logger)
      )

      return store;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just making a little mistake. you have passed this.props.leaders.leaders to RenderLeader like this:

```
<RenderLeader leaders={this.props.leaders.leaders} />
```

so you can access it in RenderLeader like directly by:

```
const leaders = props.leaders; //remove the extra '.leaders'
```